# Python 2.7.5, display count of array average, proper syntax and looping with empty space?

Tags: python, arrays, list

trying to display the count of how many values in an array are above a calculated average, when I run my code for some reason it skips the counter loop for counting the amount of student ages above the average: I load the array with 3 age values 35,25, and 50 and want to display the count of how many are above the average but it skips this? Please assist, 
Also if I want to exit the loop and not put anything on the else in a if/else, what can you put if you want empty space on the else so nothing changes? Here is my code so far:

```
st_age = [0] * 3 
for g in range(0,3):
    st_age[g] = int(input("Enter student age "))

g = 0 
sum = 0
count = 1
count2 = 0

while g < len(st_age):
    sum = sum + st_age[g]
    g += 1
average = sum / len(st_age) #the average calc. 
print "the average is:", average 
#starting counter loop here: 
g = 0
while g < len(st_age):
    if st_age[g] > average:
        count = count + 1 
    else: count = count + 1 # I don't know what to put here, it skips the whole thing

print "the number above the average is:", count
```

Comment: You probably mean to use "raw_input" rather than "input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are starter you should watch not to use function names as variables:

```
age = [3,14,55]  
sum_age = 0
count = 1
count2 = 0
g = 0  

while g < len(age):
    sum_age += age[g]
    g += 1 
average = sum_age / len(age) #the average calc. 
print "The average is:", average  

g = 0
while g < len(age):
    if age[g] > average:
        count = count + 1  
    g += 1 
print "The number above the average is:", count
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not obliged to put an `else` block. Just add 1 to `count` if the list element satisfies your condition, and don't forget to increment `g` in every case, because you are actually not traversing the list but always referring to its first element.

My proposition:

```
for age in st_age: # examine all items in st_age one by one
    if age > average:
        count += 1

print "the number above the average is:", count
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To sum all list elements, you can use built-in `sum()` function.
2. You cycle by `g`, but you never change `g` in the cycle. In other words, `g` is always equal to 0 and the `while` cycle never ends.
3. You can use list comprehensions to write this much easier. For example:

`print len(age for age in st_age if age > average)`

Answer (score 0):

"Also if I want to exit the loop and not put anything on the else in a if/else, what can you put if you want empty space on the else so nothing changes?"

you can write 
    pass
to do nothing in else part.

possible solution is :

```
st_age = [0] * 3 
for g in range(0,3):
    st_age[g] = int(input("Enter student age "))

average = sum(st_age)/len(st_age)
print "the number above the average is:", sum([1 for eachAge in st_age if eachAge>average])
```